# Header of wordpress static pages do not render correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I use WordPress on a website and the header of two static pages is not the same and I do not understand why.

- Good behavior : http://gvallver.perso.univ-pau.fr/?page_id=511
- wrong behavior : http://gvallver.perso.univ-pau.fr/ (and other pages)

Here is a screenshot, on the left the wrong behavior, on the right the good behavior :

[image]

I obtained the same rendering on Google Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you refer to the "Heading" of the page.

It looks like it's caused the ResearcherID badge that you added.

It references a CSS file at http://labs.researcherid.com/static/mashlet/css/mashlet.css which changes how the Heading is displayed.

I believe if you enter the "text" editor (rather than the visual editor), you should be able to quickly fix it.

Comment: Actually, I think I cannot remove the reference to this CSS file. This is the html code of the badge : ``<span id="badgeCont606437" style="width: 126px;"><script src="http://labs.researcherid.com/mashlets?el=badgeCont606437&amp;mashlet=badge&amp;showTitle=false&amp;className=a&amp;rid=A-1191-2012"></script></span>``. But removing these lines fix the problem.